# How to match datetime in square brackets in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match datetime which is in square brackets. I know that regEx must be used, which I am not that familiar with.

The thing I am trying to match is:
`[2020-09-04 02:17:52,146]` which can be any kind of time, not hardcoded one.

What I tried so far:
  `line = re.sub(r"\s+(?=\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\b)", "", "")` which I am expecting when I pass `line` every match of the datetime in squared brackets to be replaced with an empty string. But I am interested only in the regex for the datetime in squared brackets as defined in my question, not expecting the replacement with empty string as well.

Comment: Does `line` always contain exactly a date in the format mentioned in square brackets and nothing else, or is this only part of the string? Also, are you trying to convert it to a `datetime` object, or just test whether it matches?

Comment: yes `line` is always the same date format and I am trying to test if matches(The date is in a text and always in square brackets)

Comment: Where did you get that regular expression from? It doesn’t seem to match your described problem at all.

Comment: As I said I am not that familiar with regex, i was testing randomly at https://regex101.com/. Seems the pattern is wrong for that format and square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this pattern should do the trick:

```
r'\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]'
```

proof:
https://regexr.com/5beov

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regular expression.  One option is to try to parse it into a `datetime` object using the given format (even if you never actually use that object), and if it gives you a `ValueError` then the string was not in that format.

```
import datetime

line = "[2020-09-04 02:17:52,146]"

format = "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f]"

try:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, format)
    print(dt)
except ValueError:
    print("string is not in that format")
```

Comment: That will match only that current date, need a regex pattern for the format to match every data that has that format

Comment: If you really need a regex, you could use something like `r'\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+\]'` (I'm just checking the number of digits here - with some flexibility about the number of digits used for the fraction of a second - not whether the values are in valid range.) But this will match all the data with that format - obviously the value of `line` here is just an example.